# Music doesn't work in OpenTTD

Tags: games

I am big fan of Openttd game. In windows I just have to grab a online installer and the game runs fine smoothly. I downloaded the game .deb file from the openttd download [site](http://www.openttd.org/en/download-stable).

I installed OpenGFX and OpenSFX. But I cannot hear music. All seems to run fine. How to bring back the music? By the I am using ubuntu 11.10 32 bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jeoge! You need to install the package [timidity](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/timidity) [image: Install timidity]. You can install it by clicking on that icon or typing

```
sudo apt-get install timidity
```

in the terminal. Now you can hear music. Still have problem?
Go to OpenTTD FAQ [site](http://wiki.openttd.org/FAQ_troubleshooting).

Comment: Well thank you sir! I had this issue and I could see that the music playlist in the game menu continued to shuffle the tracks but did not play them. Only installing this package resolved the issue for me. Thanks! Edit: I just came across an other post I once resolved: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452079/no-sound-unless-root-in-debian-buster . It seems that installing timidity might interfer with overall sound functionalities in debian buster. Hopefully not in all linux distributions.